# Achievements bar is showing positive reputation gain in spite of the answer getting unaccepted?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, achievements-dialog, unaccepted-answer

On Physics.SE my [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/525339/249968) to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525337/249968) got unticked/unaccepted. I found this because my reputation got down (and surely unless I get serially downvoted or a user get removed such reputation change isn't possible). So I checked my Achievements inbox but it showed a positive reputation gain. So is this a bug?

[image: Screenshot of Achievements tab]

Note that this problem doesn't show up in the reputation history on my profile there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That +15 is caused by three upvotes (+30 reputation) minus 15 because of the unaccept. Since all events happened on the same post, they're lumped together.

I do see the unaccept in your [reputation history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/249968/johan-liebert?tab=reputation):

[image]